# I got syntax error in update statement.Run-time error: 3144 I use the following code

Tags: ms-access

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we Click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.txtdate.Tag & "" = "" Then
            'this is for insert new
            'add data to table
                CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO BphCore1(DateOfTesting, TestingAt, VoltageLevel, PolarityCheck, AppliedVoltageInPrimary, AppliedVoltageInSecondary, MeasurmentUnitIR, MinimumValue, PrimaryToEarth, PrimaryToSecondary,SecondaryToEarth, MeasurmentUnitWR, WRSecondaryValues, 20OfInjectedValue, 20OfMeasurmentValue, 40OfInjectedValue, 40OfMeasurmentValue, 60OfInjectedValue, 60OfMeasurmentValue, 80OfInjectedValue, 80OfMeasurmentValue, 100OfInjectedValue, 100OfMeasurmentValue, KneePointVoltage, MagnetizingCurrent) " & _
                        " VALUES('" & Me.txtdate & "','" & Me.cbotest & "','" & Me.cbovl & "','" & Me.cbopc & "','" & Me.cboavp & "','" & Me.cboavs & "','" & Me.cbomuir & "','" & _
                        Me.txtMV & "','" & Me.txtpe & "','" & Me.txtps & "','" & Me.txtse & "','" & Me.cbomuwr & "','" & Me.txtwrsv & "','" & Me.txti20 & "','" & Me.txtm20 & "','" & Me.txti40 & "','" & Me.txtm40 & "','" & Me.txti60 & "','" & Me.txtm60 & "','" & Me.txti80 & "','" & Me.txtm80 & "','" & Me.txti100 & "','" & Me.txtm100 & "','" & Me.txtkpv & "','" & Me.txtmc & "')"
     Else
            'otherwise (Tag of txtdate store the DateOfTesting of BphCore1 to be modified)
            CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE BphCore1 " & _
                        " SET DateOfTesting=" & Me.txtdate & _
                        ", TestingAt='" & Me.cbotest & "'" & _
                        ", VoltageLevel='" & Me.cbovl & "'" & _
                        ", PolarityCheck='" & Me.cbopc & "'" & _
                        ", AppliedVoltageInPrimary='" & Me.cboavp & "'" & _
                        ", AppliedVoltageInSecondary='" & Me.cboavs & "'" & _
                        ", MeasurmentUnitIR='" & Me.cbomuir & "'" & _
                        ", MinimumValue='" & Me.txtMV & "'" & _
                        ", PrimaryToEarth='" & Me.txtpe & "'" & _
                        ", PrimaryToSecondary='" & Me.txtps & "'" & _
                        ", SecondaryToEarth='" & Me.txtse & "'" & _
                        ", MeasurmentUnitWR='" & Me.cbomuwr & "'" & _
                        ", WRSecondaryValues='" & Me.txtwrsv & "'" & _
                        ", 20OfInjectedValue='" & Me.txti20 & "'" & _
                        ", 20OfMeasurmentValue='" & Me.txtm20 & "'" & _
                        ", 40OfInjectedValue='" & Me.txti40 & "'" & _
                        ", 40OfMeasurmentValue='" & Me.txtm40 & "'" & _
                        ", 60OfInjectedValue='" & Me.txti60 & "'" & _
                        ", 60OfMeasurmentValue='" & Me.txtm60 & "'" & _
                        ", 80OfInjectedValue='" & Me.txti80 & "'" & _
                        ", 80OfMeasurmentValue='" & Me.txtm80 & "'" & _
                        ", 100OfInjectedValue='" & Me.txti100 & "'" & _
                        ", 100OfMeasurmentValue='" & Me.txtm100 & "'" & ", KneePointVoltage='" & Me.txtkpv & "'" & ", MagnetizingCurrent='" & Me.txtmc & "'" & _
                        " WHERE DateOfTesting=" & Me.txtdate.Tag
          End If

 'clear form
     cmdclean_Click
 'refresh data in the list on form
    BphCore1subfrm.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for date/time fields use # delimiter, parameters for text fields use apostrophe delimiter, parameters for number fields do not require delimiter.

`" VALUES(#" & Me.txtdate & "#,'"`

`" SET DateOfTesting=#" & Me.txtdate & "#" & _`

`" WHERE DateOfTesting=#" & Me.txtdate.Tag & "#"`